# Volley display old data when second time loading

Tags: json, android-volley

I'm displaying list of book details in Main activity. When I added a new book, It will back to Main activity. It works perfectly. When I updated a book details, It will back to Main activity but updates are not reflecting in Main activity. If I closed and reopen the app, I can see the updates. I have tried the below.

```
queue.getCache().clear();
request.setShouldCache(false);
queue.add(request);
```